# Send push notification using GCM to multiple topics at a time in ios #ios # google-cloud-messaging

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

Id like to replace using UrbanAirship with GCM in my project.
Urban Airship allows me to create tags to a certain device and send a push notification to a Intersection of devices that fall under a tag.

**Question 1 :**
How do I achieve this with GCM with the already existing API's ? For example, If a few devices are registered for multiple topics (Region, DeviceType, Version) , I'd like to send a push to an "intersection" of devices who have registered to these topics instead of sending it the "Union" of devices ? (I'd like to send a push notification only to devices in NorthIndia for iPad with a version of 2.0).

**Question 2 :** 
I also see that for device group messaging, "The maximum number of members allowed for a notification_key is 20.” Does this mean that I can only have a max of 20 devices under one notification_key ?

Comment: I wrote to google support team and here is the reply from them : 
My understanding now is that you are inquiring about the capability to send messages to devices only where said devices are subscribed to both topic A and topic B. Unfortunately, GCM does not have this capability at the moment. In order to support this, you may have to maintain a sort of topic-subscribers mapping on your server to get the intersections.

Comment: I have similar needs in my project, to sending to union of different topics(so that device in multiple topics do not receive notification for more than once if they subscribe to multiple topics), but from the look of message format, you can't send to multiple topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer 1:** It's not possible to do that with GCM.

**Answer 2:** Yes, it means a unique user should not have more than 20 devices! :D